# Count function not complete

Tags: java, android, counter

I'm developing an app in which I need a counter. I have this counter within an `if`-clause and every time this block is triggered it should add 1 (one) to the current number. So if current number is: 1 and the if-block is triggered, the current number should be 2, then 3 for the next and so on... how ever. While testing this, the current number is changing to 2 but it wont count more. I'm sure I have written something wrong but can't seem to find what.

Code below:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float presure = event.values[0];
    altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE, presure);
    System.out.println("altitude => " + altitude);
    Log.d("SENSOR alt: ", String.valueOf(altitude));
    int currentHigh = (int) altitude;
    int reps = 1;
    if (currentHigh > 44){
        reps = reps+1;
        mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(reps));
    }
    while(reps == 5){
        Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrate.vibrate(500);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: post the entire method !

Comment: ... and strive to format your code better including use but not overuse of empty lines and whitespace.

Comment: Also, what's the point of the while there?  It will execute either 0 or 1 times, based on the break.  Use an if instead.

Comment: ANd are you sure currentHigh is still greater than 10?

Comment: Do you initialize `reps` to 1 inside the function?

Comment: Updated the code, yes i did  initialize reps to 1 thats not the point. The idea is whenever the altitude is grather than 44 (or what ever) it will count..

Comment: You need to declare the `reps` as a global variable

Comment: It's fairly clear that you're very novice at programming, and are fixated at a very specific problem. It seems to me through the various problems with your code that you might want to take a step back and improve your understanding of programming in general and Java first.

Comment: For every fire of the **onSensorChanged** event the **rep** variable is reset to one so it can never become more than two and that is only if **currentHight** condition is actually met. Make the **rep** variable Class global.

Comment: @sonnet Yes indeed!

Comment: @PaulLammertsma the thing is that im fairly new at programming, and I don't allways have time to code so when I come back i've forgot simple things like this. I fully understand what the problem was now and see that is a stupid mistake..

Comment: @Jack - Stepping through the code in your IDE's Debugger (if yours has one) would have shown you this problem right away. It's worth the few moments to study how your IDE Debugger works.

Comment: I tried to edit your original code, minimizing excess white space so that it's easy to read. I see that you've edited your question, showing more code, but you didn't put in the little effort to make the code well formatted. Please for future questions, do put in this little effort as it does make a big difference, and the effort is greatly appreciated. Why make someone else's code harder to read and understand than necessary, right?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Roger that!

Comment: @GabeSechan to answer the question,  I tried using it as a "goal". When reps is 5 it lets me know thru a vibration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the `reps` variable is your counter as this code values always `reps` 
with the `2` value and this behavior matches with your remark :

> While testing this the current number is changing too 2 but it wont
>   count more. Im sure I have written something wrong but can't seem to
>   find what.

Here you declare `reps`as a local variable and not as an instance field.
So at each call of the method, `reps` is overwritten :

```
int reps = 1;
if (currentHigh > 10) {
    reps = reps+1;
    mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(reps));
}
```

`reps == 2` after each call by assuming `currentHigh > 10`.

Just declare `reps` as an instance field (outside the method) and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you,  I didn't think of that.. But you are 100% right sir!

Comment: Another question since you are already in this thread. When I use this function and the If function is true it counts for as long as the function is true, how should I setup the same functionality for the purpose of getting "one count" rather than getting counts as long as the statement is true. if you know what I mean..I tried a while loop but didn't get me where I wanted..

Comment: "how should I setup the same functionality for the purpose of getting "one count" rather than getting counts as long as the statement is true" Sorry I am not sure to understand. Can you reformulate please ?

Comment: The string currentHigh contains the altitude, I want to count each time the device reaches the goal. When run this if statment the count is going up when the altitude is equal to 10 but it also counts while the altitude is 10. So how can I get one count for each time I reach the altitude rather then counts while being in that altitude.